# Namespace error while declare it in global scope

Tags: c++, multiple-definition-error

I have 3 files Test.h , Test.cpp and main.cpp

**Test.h**

```
#ifndef Test_H
#define Test_H
 namespace v
{
    int g = 9;;
    }
class namespce
{
public:
    namespce(void);
public:
    ~namespce(void);
};
#endif
```

**Test.cpp**

```
   #include "Test.h"


namespce::namespce(void)
{
}

namespce::~namespce(void)
{
}
```

**Main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "Test.h"
//#include "namespce.h"


int main ()
{

    return 0;

}
```

during building it gives the following error ..

```
1>namespce.obj : error LNK2005: "int v::g" (?g@v@@3HA) already defined in main.obj
1>C:\Users\E543925\Documents\Visual Studio 2005\Projects\viku\Debug\viku.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
```

kindly help as soon as possible ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

static:

```
namespace v
{
    static int g = 9; //different copy of g per translation unit
}
```

extern:

```
namespace v
{
    extern int g; //share g between units
}

// add initialization to .cpp:
namespace v { int g = 9; }
```

Answer (score 5):

This is a definition:

```
namespace v
{
    int g = 9;
}
```

that gets duplicated in `main.obj` and `test.obj` due to the `#include "Test.h"` in each of the `.cpp` files. The include guard `#ifndef Test_H` only prevents multiple inclusions in a single translation unit.

Change to:

```
namespace v
{
    extern int g; // This is now a declaration and extern tells the compiler
                  // that there is definition for g somewhere else.
}
```

and add the following to the `Test.cpp`:

```
namespace v
{
    int g = 9; // This is now the ONLY definition of 'g', in test.obj.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You want just one instance of `g` accessed by everyone?
In the header, use

```
extern int g; // declaration
```

in Test.cpp, put

```
int v::g = 9; //definition
```