# Multiple defintion error in SDL program

Tags: c++, sdl, definition

I have a problem with multiple definitions with the variable's `beeld`, `knop`, `clips`, `foto`, `text`, `font`, `fontkleur`, `muziek`, `event`.
The problems are mostly in these files:

globals.h

```
#ifndef globals_H
#define globals_H

#include "SDL/SDL.h"
#include "SDL/SDL_image.h"
#include "SDL/SDL_ttf.h"
#include "SDL/SDL_mixer.h"

SDL_Surface *beeld = NULL;
SDL_Surface *knop = NULL;
SDL_Rect clips[ 4 ];
SDL_Surface *foto = NULL;
SDL_Surface *text = NULL;
TTF_Font *font = NULL;
SDL_Color fontkleur = { 100, 0, 10 };
Mix_Music *muziek = NULL;
SDL_Event event;

#endif
```

main.cpp

```
#include "SDL/SDL.h"
#include "SDL/SDL_image.h"
#include "SDL/SDL_ttf.h"
#include "SDL/SDL_mixer.h"

#include "variabelen.h"
#include "class.h"
#include "functies.h"
#include "globals.h"

#include <string>


int main( int argc, char* args[] )
{
    bool stop = false;
    if( init(beeld_L,beeld_H,beeld_BPP) == false )
    {
        return 1;
    }

    foto = zichtbaar_scherm( "rescource/achtergrond.png" );
    knop = zichtbaar_scherm( "rescource/knop.png" );
    font = TTF_OpenFont( "rescource/lazy.ttf", 80 );
    muziek = Mix_LoadMUS( "rescource/muziek.wma" );

    laad_prenten(foto);
    laad_prenten(knop);
    laad_text(font);
    laad_muziek(muziek);

    if( laad_prenten(foto) == false || laad_prenten(knop) == false || laad_text(font) == false || laad_muziek(muziek) == false )
    {
        return 1;
    }

    set_clips();

    Knop drukknop( 170, 180, 320, 120 );

    plus_laag( 0, 0, foto, beeld );

    text = TTF_RenderText_Solid( font, "START !", fontkleur );
    plus_laag( ( 320 - text->w ) / 2, 30, text, knop );
    Mix_PlayMusic( muziek, -1 );

    while( stop == false )
    {
        if( SDL_PollEvent( &event ) )
        {


            if( event.type == SDL_QUIT )
            {
                stop = true;
            }
            if( drukknop.events() == true )
            {
                stop = true;
            }
        }
        drukknop.toon();

        if( SDL_Flip( beeld ) == -1 )
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    afsluiten();

    return 0;
}
```

the programme makes a small menu :D

Comment: Would you care to put the relevant code HERE rather than in a link ?

Comment: Presumably there is another `.cpp` file that `#include globals.h`? If so, this should explain it (among other duplicates of multiple definition errors) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11686508/namespace-error-while-declare-it-in-global-scope/11686576#11686576 . Just to point out it is unrelated to SDL.

Answer (score 4):

Defining variables as you do in the .h file has a serious problem. Such a definition reserves space for that variable so that if you include such a .h file in two different C++ files you get separate instances in EACH c++ module which gives you a conflict when it comes to linking.

Normally in the .h files variables are **declared** (but not defined) extern like so

```
extern int X;
```

This makes the symbol valid but does NOT reserve memory so if you include the extern keyword then the problem with multiple definitions goes away.
However  you do need ONE real full **definition** in ONE module (perhaps your main.cpp file)

```
int X=0;
```

Comment: Technically what's currently in the header file is a definition, not a declaration which is exactly the source of the problem.

Comment: I fixed up the vocabulary on the answer a bit as suggested by @Flexco

Comment: That wasn't quite the edit I was thinking of - I made the edit, if you don't like it feel free to roll back.

Comment: Just tired and stupid yesterday - thanks for the re-edit